# Convert string containing code for a React class into a usable component?

Tags: reactjs

If you had a string containing the code for a React class, how would you display that class as a component?

```
const hello = `class Hello extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            clicks: 0
        }
    }

    onHelloClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({ clicks: this.state.clicks + 1 })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hello!</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}`
```

My goal is to render the component `<Hello />` from within the project.

Comment: What's the goal here? Why's it a string?

Comment: It's a string because it's user input from an in-browser code editor.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the answer to your question is [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). But as the documentation points out, it is an enormous security concern and generally not recommended.

However, there is a complication. `JSX` is not valid javascript and needs to be transpiled, typically with a tool like [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react). You *could* write the component [without JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html) but that is very tedious. The easiest would be to make sure your code is transpiled beforehand.